# Python library: function inside function returns none

Tags: python

I'm making a python library that allows encrypting and decrypting strings of text. (Encryption: It finds any letter and changes it to respective one in key. Decryption: It finds specific strings inside string and changes to respective letters that are respective to key.) When calling my library's functions (any of them except keygen) it outputs none, but it should not output none. It also was destroying any whitespaces in the string put into encryption function.

Here is my code:

```
class mjk614:

    def generate_random_key():
        import random
        result_str = ''.join((random.choice('QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890') for i in range(279)))
        return result_str
        

    global characters

    import textwrap
    
    all_characters_not_wrapped = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM!@#$%^&*()_+1234567890-= qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm[];',./|\{}:\"<>?"
    characters = textwrap.wrap(all_characters_not_wrapped, 1)

    def encrypt(string, decryptionkey):

        import textwrap
        
        global ready2
        global ready
        global main

        lines2 = string
        ready = textwrap.wrap(lines2, 1)
        ready2 = ready

        key = textwrap.wrap(decryptionkey, 3)

        main = 0

        def cycle():
            global main
            for x in range(999):
                try:
                    if characters[x] == ready[(0+main)]:
                        ready2[0+main] = key[x]
                        main = main+1
                        cycle()
                        break
                except IndexError:
                    write(ready2)
                    break
                 

        def write(current):
            res = str(current)[1:-1]
            res1 = res.replace("[", "")
            res2 = res1.replace("]", "")
            res3 = res2.replace(", ", "")
            global res4
            res4 = res3.replace("'", "")
            return res4
            exit


    def decrypt(string, decryptionkey):

        import textwrap

        global key2
        key2 = textwrap.wrap(decryptionkey, 3)
        
        def RUNDECRYPTION(string):

            import textwrap

            global ready3
            global ready2
            
            lines2 = string
            ready3 = textwrap.wrap(lines2, 3)
            ready2 = ready3
            
            global main
            main = 0

            def cycle():
                global main
                for x in range(999):
                    try:
                        if key2[x] == ready3[(0+main)]:
                            ready2[0+main] = characters[x]
                            main = main+1
                            cycle()
                            break
                    except IndexError:
                        write(ready2)
                        break
            
            def write(current):
                res = str(current)[1:-1]
                res1 = res.replace("[", "")
                res2 = res1.replace("]", "")
                res3 = res2.replace(", ", "")
                global res4
                res4 = res3.replace("'", "")
                return res4
                exit

            cycle()

        RUNDECRYPTION(string)
```

I tried:

```
print(mjk614.decrypt("BeH65WpLMBeH", "PzekfhhIf7SRwnLmGFYOaS7GIrcVLuXMZzvbmXOesfkvfywvGG5kZoqRrrIFAbiydcIH2YeMFUqWTN1Oz7PexTOBon6PL5HEqQtjEsXdf6rihO7jfkUUF7bGUE6MSYS8xBgmffU7SVqtMyIbTHycRangNjDe65WBhDBeHcIUuJgc7Rqm74KghEOtFcLeS0sR1udLSJt4Upv3ObwRj4pLMR4voBIZaivHGnOPExxZPoJ2O3fPXiFKvAwoxmRMcckGIUSAD6BuDWGhdf3PaHmk8Hq"))
```

Should have returned:

"Text"

Returned:

"None"

Comment: `decrypt` for example doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: You appear to be using globals to act as pseudo-return values. You can't print the returned value of `decrypt` though like you're trying if `decrypt` doesn't `return` anything. Also note, `exit` isn't doing anything there.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I do not understand what do you mean... can you please say this but in easier terms?

Comment: None if this should be in a class definition. You are using that incorrectly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but i am making a library?...

Comment: In order to do `print(func())`, `func` must `return` a value. Otherwise, `None` is implicitly returned. You'll want to review how to use `return`, and then refactor your functions to use it. The current organization of your functions makes suggesting a fix hard.

Comment: And you don't need a `class` to make a library. The module itself acts as a namespace.

Comment: What is your point? You don't need a class to make a library, and you certainly don't need a class that is implemented incorrectly. Frankly, and I'm not trying to be mean, but you code shows several signs of not really understanding the fundamentals of the language. I would suggest to stop trying to use a feature like a class definition without understanding how basic functions and return values work

Comment: I have to agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga. Also, the use of `global` is almost always a mistake; i.e., it indicates a bad design. But the most important thing is that you should never, **ever**, write your own encryption logic except as a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this code by changing it to:

```
class mjk614:
    def generate_random_key():
        import random
        result_str = ''.join((random.choice('QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890') for i in range(279)))
        return result_str
        

    global characters

    import textwrap

    all_characters_not_wrapped = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM!@#$%^&*()_+1234567890-= qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm[];',./|\{}:\"<>?"
    characters = textwrap.wrap(all_characters_not_wrapped, 1)

    def encrypt(string, decryptionkey):

        import textwrap
        
        global ready2
        global ready
        global main

        lines2 = string
        ready = textwrap.wrap(lines2, 1)
        ready2 = ready

        key = textwrap.wrap(decryptionkey, 3)

        main = 0

        def cycle():
            global main
            for x in range(90):
                try:
                    if characters[x] == ready[(0+main)]:
                        ready2[0+main] = key[x]
                        main = main+1
                        return cycle()
                        break
                except IndexError:
                    res = str(ready2)[1:-1]
                    res1 = res.replace("[", "")
                    res2 = res1.replace("]", "")
                    res3 = res2.replace(", ", "")
                    global res4
                    res4 = res3.replace("'", "")
                    return res4
                    break

        return cycle()

    def decrypt(string, decryptionkey):

        import textwrap

        global key2
        global ready3
        global ready2
        
        key2 = textwrap.wrap(decryptionkey, 3)
            
        lines2 = string
        ready3 = textwrap.wrap(lines2, 3)
        ready2 = ready3
            
        global main
        main = 0

        def cycle():
            global main
            for x in range(999):
                try:
                    if key2[x] == ready3[(0+main)]:
                        ready2[0+main] = characters[x]
                        main = main+1
                        return cycle()
                        break
                except IndexError:
                    res = str(ready2)[1:-1]
                    res1 = res.replace("[", "")
                    res2 = res1.replace("]", "")
                    res3 = res2.replace(", ", "")
                    global res4
                    res4 = res3.replace("'", "")
                    return res4
                    break

        return cycle()
```

But, it still does not like whitespaces.
But still, thanks to everyone who answered my original question.